# Is there any in-browser online tool for marking bounded boxes of objects in images for training neural networks?

Tags: neural-network, yolo, bounding-box, darknet

I want to create my own dataset for [YOLOv3 Object Detection](https://medium.com/@duraklefkan/training-yolov3-object-detection-api-with-your-own-dataset-4dcfc7c1c34c). It looks like there is a huge set of offline tools for marking bounded boxes, for example: [Yolo_mark](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/Yolo_mark), [Microsoft VoTT](https://github.com/microsoft/VoTT), [LabelImg](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg). Is there any zero-config online tool, which will work right in my web browser? Also It would also be convenient to be able to crop [ROI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Region_of_interest) of the image right in the process of marking along with bounding boxes.

[image: Yolo_mark]

Answer (score -1):

I could not find a tool that fit the search criteria, so I decided to write it myself. It published by [direct link](https://yolo-mark-pwa.github.io/) in Github Pages. A killer feature of this tool is support for touch screen input. ROI cropping with automatic shift of bounding boxes is also implemented.

[image]

Source code is published [here](https://github.com/tripolskypetr/material-ui-umd/tree/master/packages/yolo-mark-pwa). The tool uses a minimum of third-party dependencies: only  Typescript compiler is required for deployment. Bounding boxes will be written when saved onto txt files by [darknet](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet) framework format.

Comment: Lol. People dislike but continue googling question after three years